# Error: The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server

Tags: ftp, filezilla

When connecting to internet address in the FTP client we get an error
Error: The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server

When connecting through same client to FTP server error does not occur (When connecting through local LAN’s clients)

Window Firewall is off.

Tried with changing ports.

We have two server running fine .So network configuration is done proper.

Error log is :

```
Status: Connecting to 117.247.9.3:2555...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.40 beta
Response:   220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
Response:   220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
Command:    USER ++++
Response:   331 Password required for ++++
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   230 Logged on
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,78,5,245)
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command:    MLSD
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
Response:   425 Can't open data connection.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing


Status: Connecting to 117.247.9.3:2555...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.40 beta
Response:   220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
Response:   220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
Command:    USER ++++
Response:   331 Password required for ++++
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   230 Logged on
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,78,5,255)
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command:    MLSD
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
Response:   425 Can't open data connection.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,78,5,245)
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
```

It looks like the server is inside a private network, that is behind a router/firewall. But you access the server from outside the private network. Unless the router/firewall has special helpers to deal with this situation and to rewrite the traffic this will not work with passive mode. Given the above response from the server received by the client you have no such router/firewall.

In this case you would have to need active mode. But, if both client and server are behind such a router/firewall and are in different networks even active mode will not work.

Comment: We configured through router.How to make it work in active mode?

Comment: That's a client side setting which depends on your ftp client. Just look at the settings in FileZilla. But again, if the client itself is inside a private network active mode will not help.

Comment: When set to active mode we get                                Status: Connecting to 117.247.9.3:2555...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error: Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 117.247.9.3:2555...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: Looks like you have a firewall blocking connection to your client, either a firewall on the client itself or a separate system. That's the reason one usually uses passive mode - but unfortunately passive mode will not work with the setup/location of your server.

Answer (score 3):

```
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,78,5,245)
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command:    MLSD
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
Response:   425 Can't open data connection.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

**I.** You are using Passive mode to connect to server. Passive mode connect to server, it will open a random port above 1023. So if you are using iptables on the server, you need do 2 things:

1. Edit iptables config file. Append 2 rows:

   ```
   -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
   -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 10000:10100 -j ACCEPT
   ```
2. Edit /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf. Append these lines:

   ```
   pasv_enable=YES
   pasv_max_port=10100
   pasv_min_port=10000
   port_enable=YES
   pasv_address=158.199.195.249
   ```

**II.** Easier way to fix.

Go to FileZilla -> Settings -> FTP -> Switch "Passive mode" to "Active"