# FileZilla Critical file transfer error

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, file-transfer, upload

I use FileZilla to transfer my images to my hosting server.

This error appears all the time

> Status:   Starting upload of M:\LMG Jewellery\Images to upload\Lot 5 images\PJSMGSNK1455WL20.PT03.jpg
> Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
> Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
> Command:    STOR PJSMGSNK1455WL20.PT02.jpg
> **Error:    Critical file transfer error**

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Post a full verbose log file. + Does any other FTP client work? – This looks like a firewall or NAT problem. Where are you connecting from? Can you connect to any FTP server at all? What exactly is the *"hosting server"*? Is it a physical or virtual server? Or just a web hosting?

Answer (score 0):

"Server sent passive reply with unroutable address." means that the server is responding with an address that your computer can't hit. Usually, this means that the server is behind a NAT, and is responding with a private IP.

Your server needs to be configured to present its external IP address to clients, and have the appropriate ports forwarded.

There's another question along these lines [here](https://superuser.com/questions/801407/error-the-data-connection-could-not-be-established-econnrefused-connection-r), but I wouldn't call it a direct duplicate. The method used to set the external IP varies per FTP server.